# Django object of type fraction is not json serializable

Tags: python-3.x, django, jsonresponse

```
from django.http import JsonResponse, HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from math import sqrt
from fractions import Fraction




def index(request):
    return render(request, 'home/index.html', {})

def multiplication(request):
    return render(request, 'multiplication/multiplication.html', {})


def compute(request):
    a = int(request.POST.get("a"))
    b = int(request.POST.get("b"))
    c = int(request.POST.get("c"))
    det = b*b-4*a*c
    rdet = sqrt(det)
    x1= (-b-rdet)/(2*a)
    x2= (-b+rdet)/(2*a)
    x3= Fraction(15, 45)
    return JsonResponse({"op_result": det, "op_result2": x1, "op_result3": x2, "op_result4": 2*a, "op_result5": -b, "op_result6": c,"op_result7": x3})
```

in my view.py, I tried to send back to my html, the results of the function fractions through the var x3

x3= Fraction(15, 45) and sent the result with JsonResponse. But I have an error message :

object of type fraction is not json serializable

I do not understand where is the mistake.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Well as the error indicates: you can not serialize a `Fraction`.

Comment: Thanks for your replyOk. So what do you suggest to return a fraction through Json. Any Idea ?

Comment: JSON only knows about standard types.  integer, float, string, list, dictionary.  It does not know how to handle custom classes like Fraction.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot serialize a fraction but can make a custom serializer and pass numerator and denominator in that

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.views import View
from fractions import Fraction
import json

class FractionEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, Fraction):
            return {"numerator": obj.numerator, "denominator": obj.denominator}
        return super().default(obj)

class generate_dummy_energy_usage(View):
    def get(self,request):
        a = 10
        b = 40
        c = 30
        det = b*b-4*a*c
        rdet = sqrt(det)
        x1 = (-b-rdet)/(2*a)
        x2 = (-b+rdet)/(2*a)
        x3 = Fraction(15, 45)
        return JsonResponse({"op_result": det, "op_result2": x1, "op_result3": x2, "op_result4": 2*a, "op_result5": -b, "op_result6": c, "op_result7": x3}, encoder=FractionEncoder)
```

this is output in jsonresponse 
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

rather than sending as fraction just compute it and send it as string would be a easier approach

[image: response]

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your reply. Ok I understand the point to send a string. can you just help me to adapt my script in html to call the new function. Here is the script

Comment: i cannot see the scripts

Comment: Dear Dhruv Patel, thank you for your help. I found a solution and it works thanks to your help.

I just have a question, because I need to get the numerator and denominator digit.
in my html page. I recover the sentence {"numerator": -1;"denominator:2}

but can extract -1 and 2 for example only in the html page?

Comment: ok now with return obj.numerator , obj.denominator i get in the HTML file by resultParagraph4.innerHTML =JSON.stringify(result["op_result7"]); a result as follow :
[-1,2] .. for -1/2 as fraction. Do you think I can get -1 and 2 separatly ? in fact I need to rewrite the fraction with Mathjax. So I need them separetly

Comment: try printing op_result7.numerator and opresult7.denominator it should work, actually i dont know how you are sending data to html, second way is if you are getting [-1,2] from JSON.stringify(result["op_result7"]), then just store that array and do array[0] and array[1] that way also you can get the seperated values

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.querySelector("#fetch-call").addEventListener("click", event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    let form = new FormData();

    form.append("a", document.querySelector("#a").value);
    form.append("b", document.querySelector("#b").value);
    form.append("c", document.querySelector("#c").value);

    let csrfTokenValue = document.querySelector('[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').value;
    let request = new Request("{% url 'compute' %}", {method: 'POST',
                                                      body: form,
                                                      headers: {"X-CSRFToken": csrfTokenValue}})
    fetch(request)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(result => {
            let resultParagraph = document.querySelector("#operation");
            resultParagraph.innerHTML ="Le discriminant "+"\\(\\Delta\\)"+" =" + result["op_result"] ;
            MathJax.typeset();

            let resultParagraph2 = document.querySelector("#operation2");
            resultParagraph2.innerHTML ="La solution x1 est :"+"\\("+result["op_result5"]+"-"+"\\sqrt"+result["op_result"]+"\\over"+result["op_result4"]+"\\)"+" et la solution x2 est :"+"\\("+result["op_result5"]+"+"+"\\sqrt"+result["op_result"]+"\\over"+result["op_result4"]+"\\)";
            MathJax.typeset();
            
            let resultParagraph3 = document.querySelector("#operation3");
            resultParagraph3.innerHTML ="la valeur approchée de x1 est: " + result["op_result2"] + " et x2 est : "+ result["op_result3"];
            
            let resultParagraph4 = document.querySelector("#operation4");
            resultParagraph4.innerHTML ="facration " + result["op_result7"];
            
                   })
})
```